# Is a straight URL echo XSS unusable in a modern environment?

Tags: web-browser, xss

So I've been doing a red team exercise and one internal app echos back `Cannot find /whatever/your/path`. Since this is not a PHP or even fully featured web server there is no magical automatic decoding so if you send in `/%00%0d%25/stuff` you'll get `Cannot find /%00%0d%25/stuff`

The issue is that every single browser in recent history either automatically encodes `<` or `>` or is intelligent enough to not render the non-HTML page (since there's no HTML tags it interprets the string into a renderable context) as HTML. I've tested every browser that we currently have in operation and not a single one has generated an XSS condition because they either correctly encoded the URL and any parameters or escaped the non-HTML document so that it can be rendered as seemingly plaintext.

Am I right to assume that unless combined with another far more significant vulnerability this is unexploitable unless you happen to be running Netscape 1.0 or some other equally poor (and unapproved) browser?

Comment: @Arminius that appears to answer the first part (is any current browser vulnerable) but there still remains the bit of is it possible to change the way the browser guesses the content type when a header isn't returned.

Comment: @Sirens: instead of adding an essentially new question to an existing one because the existing one was correctly marked as duplicate you should ask your new question in a new question, not in an edit.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich your wish is my command

Answer (score 0):

Browsers interprets pages as HTML when the HTTP response headers contains "Content-Type: text/html".

If the response contains "Content-Type: text/plain", then the text is interpreted as plain text and the text will be displayed as is, no HTML interpretation will be done to the text.

Comment: That wasn't really the question, I was wondering if there is a way to get a browser to send characters as part of a URL without encoding them